# How & what can i use to connect AWS API-Gateways to RDS without lambda?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I've set up a AWS RDS on a EC2 Instance with a MySQL database on it. Now im trying to acces it with API-Gateway. Ive tried to implement Lambda but i dont have the necessary privileges to do so.

Now im searching for a new solution.

[ChatGPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKohb.png)

ChatGPT gave me these options but i havent found any good tutorials on any of them online.
Usage of API-Gateway isn't fully necessary, if there's a similar service thats fine with me.

If anyone has a somewhat good suggestion, i would be very thankful.

Comment: RDS is amazon's relational database service; if you are using your own EC2 instance you are not using RDS.

Comment: right, you see im not very experienced. Do you have recommendations for when i do use RDS instead of EC2? Or else, services to create a connection to the database on the EC2 Instance? @ysth

Comment: RDS does more for you, EC2 gives you more control.  But afaik that isn't related to your question.  I don't know anything about API Gateway or what it does, so I can't help you there.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have enough privileges?

Answer (score 0):

I am partially not clear about your question. But, if you are trying to connect RDS via API gateway. Following workflow pattern would be great helpful. Since Api gateway and lambda has direct integration.

Api GW -> Lambda -> RDS

if you are looking for more scale and latency. would recommend you to check following link.

https://www.workfall.com/learning/blog/how-to-improve-application-availability-with-amazon-rds-proxy/